# Associate work item or code review to a changeset after check in

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to update a changeset to include a reference to a work item after the check in has occurred? For instance you can right click on a changeset, and request a review (rather than requesting a review based on a shelveset before check in).

This may not be "best practices", but in that scenario is it possible to add a reference to that code review to the change set? The code review of course has a reference to the changeset, but it is not a two way association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manually associate a changeset to a code review so that the code review shows up as a related work item in that changeset's details requires you to modify the work item form for the Code Review Request work item type. This requires the use of the TFS Process Template Editor.

### TFS Versions supported

- **TFS 2015 | TFS 2013 | TFS 2012**
  The steps below should be supported on these on premise deployments.
- **Azure DevOps Services (Hosted XML) | TFS 2018 | TFS 2017**
  The work item form was redesigned in TFS 2017 and some of the XML used below [was deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/linkscontroloptions-xml-elements?view=azure-devops). If anyone can provide an equivalent definition for these newer versions I can update this answer.

### Install Process Template Editor

Download and install the appropriate version of the Process Template Editor based on the version of Visual Studio that you have:

- VS 2015: [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)
- VS 2017: [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor)
- VS 2019: [Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte)

### Modify the Code Review Request work item definition

Once the Process Template Editor is installed, follow these steps to update the Code Review Request work item form.

1. Open the Code Review Request work item type definition from the server.

   1. Open Visual Studio and go to **Tools** > **Process Editor** > **Work Items** > **Open WIT From Server**.
   2. In the **Connect to Team Project Collection** dialog, select the appropriate collection and click **Connect**.
   3. Expand your team project, select **Code Review Request** and click **OK**.
2. Add a new control for changeset links.

   1. In the **Work Item Type** window, click the **Layout** tab.
   2. Navigate to **Layout** > **TabGroup** > **Tab Page - Links**.
   3. Right-click **Tab Page - Links** and select **New Control**.
   4. Set the following properties:

      1. **Type**: LinksControl
      2. **Label**: Changeset
      3. **Label** Position: Top
      4. **Name**: ChangesetLink
   5. In the properties panel, find the **Control Settings** property and click the **...** button to the right of "LinksControlOptionsType".
   6. If you see an error that says "Failed to load Control Settings" you should be able to safely dismiss it.
   7. On the **XML** tab, enter the following code and click **OK**:

      ```xml
      <LinksControlOptionsType>
      <LinkColumns>
          <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
          <LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment" />
      </LinkColumns>
      <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="excludeAll" />
      <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="include">
          <Filter LinkType="Fixed in Changeset" />
      </ExternalLinkFilters>
      </LinksControlOptionsType>
      ```
3. Update the server with your changes.

   1. Save the file. This will create one file with a `.wit` extension and one with a `.xml` extension.
   2. Go to **Tools** > **Process Editor** > **Work Items** > **Import WIT**.
   3. In the **Connect to Team Project Collection** dialog, select the appropriate collection and click **Connect**.
   4. In the **Import Work Item Type Definition** dialog, select the team project from the list.
   5. Click **Browse...**, select the **`.XML`** file, and click **Open**. Then click **OK**.

### Adding the link

After updating the work item type definition, users may first need to click the refresh button in Team Explorer or in the browser the changes will be recognized.

#### Using Visual Studio

1. Open the Code Review Request

   - Use **Team** > **Go to Work Item...**, OR
   - Enter the code review id in **Team Explorer**'s **Search Work Items** field.
2. Open the work item form by clicking **Actions** in the Team Explorer pane, and then click **Open Work Item #**
3. Navigate to the **Links** tab, scroll down to the **Changeset** control, and click **Link to**.
4. Enter the changeset id and click **OK**.

#### Using the TFS Web Interface

1. Open the TFS web interface.
2. Enter the code review id in the **Search work items** field.
3. Navigate to the **Links** tab, scroll down to the **Changeset** control, and click **Link to**.
4. Enter the changeset id and click **OK**.

Answer (score 26):

Open the Work Item, select "All Links", select the "Link To" button, then "Changeset".

[image: Link To Dialog]

You can then either enter the changeset number, or use "..." to browse.

Comment: I'm curious where you see this screen? I have VS 2012 maybe that's why but mine don't look exactly like this. Regardless, I do see something similar on Bugs. But I do not have the same options on **code reviews**. From the web interface only, I can link to an item, but from the site I cannot set changeset as a link type. From the interface inside Visual Studio the Add Link button is disabled for some reason.

Comment: this is the we interface, the visual studio one look very similar.  You can do the same thing there.

Comment: To reiterate, this doesn't work for me except for the case of attaching a work item like a bug to a changeset after it's been checked in. This does not work for creating a link ON a changeset, TO a code review, in the case where a code review was created using Etienne's process above. The code review is linked to the changeset, but the changeset will not be linked to the code review. No one can view that changeset later, and see that yes there was indeed a code review. So far I have not found a way to do that.

Comment: Agree with @Malaise.. The question is asking about how the Work Item can be associated TO a Changeset Item.

Answer (score 18):

Note that you can also conduct a code review on a checked-in changeset by going to the history right-clicking on the changeset and selecting

[image]

Comment: Yes! Exactly. This what I'm talking about. What I'm saying is that in my system, it appears that this changeset is not linked to the code review that's created. The code review is linked to the changeset, but not the other way around. I was hoping to "edit" the changeset, so that when someone views the changeset, they can see the code review linked there. Right now that is not happening.

Comment: So what I showed was to do a review after a check-in occurred.  But if you want you can use Edward's suggestion to attach a changeset after the fact.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103788/tfs-2012-how-can-i-tell-if-a-changeset-was-code-reviewed

Comment: See also https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6104804-allow-the-ability-to-prove-that-a-code-review-was

Answer (score 3):

Here is a screenshot of a shared query my team uses to find a code review:

[image: TFS code review query]

I can find a code review work item for a specific work item by entering that work Item number in the filter field on the results tab for the query in the screenshot I attached.

This way, I can find the code review work item for any changeset, as long as that changeset was associated with a TFS work item.