# TFS Query for Changesets without Code Review

Tags: tfs, review

Anyone knows how to search for changesets with no Associated Code Review with a TFS Query or similar? It can be also a query on TFS Data Warehouse.

Comment: Either the warehouse or using a small powershell snippet through the API. Work item queries won't help you.

Comment: Can you provide any example of powershell for that? Thanks!!

Comment: Check out; https://github.com/igoravl/tfscmdlets

Answer (score -1):

When you request a code review from a changeset, it's **not Bi-directional**, only link one way.

This means you can't directly know if a changeset was code-reviewed or not from changeset ID. To get the association, you need to go through work item. There 's a work item called **code review work item**, a sample query as below, through that way you could find the code review work item  for any changeset, as long as that changeset was associated with a TFS work item.

[image]

However, for your requirement, it's not able to use a work item query to do this. You may have to use TFS API to ahcieve it just as *jessehouwing* suggested.

Comment: Thanks! I already have the same queries for that purpose, but i was more interested in following "not code-reviewed changeset" rather than having the list of code reviews done. Can you provide any example code or SQL for that?